# Nonautonomous linear matrix ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

d/dt Ø = A(t)*Ø, Ø(0,0)=I

The task is as follows: An obvious guess for the solution is the exponential Ø(t0,t)=exp(∫(from t0 to t) A(s)ds) . Expand this exponential in a series, keeping terms to second order (quadratic terms in A). Substitute the result into the ODE and show that it is generally not correct to this order.

Comment: The question seems clear. What is your problem?

Comment: How do I substitute it into the ODE?